# Docker postgres container loses data that should be stored in volume

Tags: windows, postgresql, docker

I am running a postgres database generated by the below docker-compose file on Windows. Before running `docker-compose up --build`, I created a docker volume with `docker volume --name postgresdata --driver local`. The latter is done to avoid mounting a Windows folder into Postgres.

However, when I run `docker-compose down` followed by `docker-compose up --build`, the database is empty which I would not have expected. Any ideas or suggestions?

This is the docker-compose.yml file I am using:

```
version: '3.0'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    env_file:
      - env_file
    volumes:
      - postgresdata
    networks:
     - db1

  market_data:
    build: .
    environment:
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 'true'
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    links:
     - db:db
    container_name: market_data_container
    volumes:
     - '.:/market_data'
    depends_on:
     - db
    networks:
     - db1

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
     - db1
    depends_on:
     - db


volumes:
 market_data:
 postgresdata:
  external: true

networks:
 db1:
  driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postgres uses already a [volume](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/0aaaf2094034647a552f0b1ec63b1b0ec0f6c2cc/10/Dockerfile#L126) to persist data, but `docker-compose down` deletes this volume. You are using named volumes in your compose file, but don't mount it correctly.

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    env_file:
      - env_file
    volumes:
      - postgresdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
     - db1
```

Add the default path for postgres data to your volume `postgresdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data`. This should fix it.

Comment: this fixes it! Thanks :)